# Highcharts date in form of Day(Integer) - Month(the name of the month), like 17 - July

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I tried below

```
point.date:%d-%m
```

in a tooltip to display the date time but it shows like 16-06. Is there a way to show it like 31 December?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `%B` for full month name or `%b` for abbreviated month name:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.date:%d-%B}'
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lc17z0v8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

Useful link: https://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php